# integrate tkinter whit Sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm looking for a suggestion: I have a Module called main.py where I write all GUI code.In order to avoid repeating all the sqlite queries, I have written all those queries un other Module called admin.py.
So there is this code in main.py:

```
B = tk.Entry()
B1= B.get()
```

In admin.py, I have the method validate.That is supposed take the B variable to make the query.Something like:

```
//Here the function will query the db to see if the value in B1.get() exist//
class myclass()
    def validate(a):
    ....SELECT FROM table WHERE col_val = (a)
```

And here is the trouble: I don't know how to pass the value of B1 to the validate method. Could be something like this:

```
s= myclass()
s.validate(B1)
```

maybe?

Comment: please create a [mcve] that we can use to duplicate what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've done but i think could be better.Here is the way i did. Sorry for question i wasn't in the computer.

There is the module main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import ingreso
from tkinter import messagebox
from ingreso import myclass    
import sqlite3
 def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            frame = tk.Frame(self,width=380, height=420, bg="white", colormap="new")
            self.fi = tk.Entry(frame)
            self.fi.pack()
            self.dni = tk.Entry(frame)
            self.dni.pack()
            frame.pack()
            self.hi = tk.Button(self,text="guardar", command= self.validate)
            self.hi.pack()

        def validate(self):
            messagebox.showwarning(title="validador",message="Se procedera a validar los campos")
            fi= self.fi.get() #That is that i pass as class argument
            dni= self.dni.get()
            if len(fi)== 0 or len(dni)==0:
                tk.messagebox.showwarning(message="campos requeridos")
            else:
                query = myclass(fi, dni) #Create the objet at instance of class
                val = query.validar()    #Determine if the object exist or not
```

There is the module ingreso.py:

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self, a= " ", b= " "):  #There is the attributes of the class
        self.db = db
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def validar(self): # here i determine if the objet exist or not
        fi = self.a
        dni = self.b
        conn = sqlite3.connect('ecina.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM admision WHERE fi = (?) AND dni =(?)''', (fi, dni))
        r = c.fetchone()
        number_of_rows=r[0]
        return number_of_rows
```

It's works but any suggestion or correction will be very appreciate.Thanks Alot.